# Getting an Invalid Credentials error in my Django login endpoint after access token has expired

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, postman, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using djangorestframework-simplejwt to configure authentication for my django app. I have configured a login view to authenticate a user with an email and password and I have a login endpoint to test if it is working correctly.

When I log in a user with email and password, I am successfully logged in and an access token which could be used to maintain the session is generated. Problem is, after the token has expired, I am getting an invalid credentials error even though the email and password are correct.

I suspect that the authenticate object is returning None for some reason after the token has expired or I may have configured simplejwt incorrectly.

Below is my login view

```
class login_view(APIView):
    """Logs in a user"""

    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]

    def post(self, request):
        target_email = os.environ.get('TARGET_EMAIL')
        email = request.data.get('email')
        password = request.data.get('password')

        if email != target_email:
            return Response({'error': 'Invalid email'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            # Generate Access Token and Refresh Token
            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
            access_token = str(refresh.access_token)
            refresh_token = str(refresh)
            
            #jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
            #jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER
            #payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
            #token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
            return Response({'access_token': access_token, 'refresh_token': refresh_token})

        else:
            return Response({'error': 'Invalid credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

My simplejwt config

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
           # 'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
            'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
            ),
        }

from datetime import timedelta

SIMPLE_JWT = {
        'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=4),
        'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=7),
        }
```

My user model

```
# Create your models here.
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """An admin user manager"""
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Creates a standard user using email"""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Email field should be set")
        email = email.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

"""def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        Creates an admin user
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_staff=True")
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_superuser=True")
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)"""


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    #is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    #date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

I commented out some code. Check only the uncommented code thanks

In the login view,  I tried inserting the code `user = authenticate(request, email, password)` to see if that will allow for reaunthication. Also, I set `is.active()` to True in the user model. Currently, the only way I can log in successfully is if I reset a user's password

Comment: I'm not able to understand your flow. generally ,The login page is usually accessible to everyone, including anonymous users who are not authenticated.the login page itself does not require authentication because it's the entry point for users to provide their credentials and authenticate for further routes(urls). is there any specific requirement do you have?